# Xamarin storyboard not loading on Mac or windows

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Storyboard doesn't load on Windows or on Mac. Both are updated to the latest version and I am using xcode 11.3.

Mac: Mac version 8.3.11 
Mono: 6.6.0.155

> [2019-12-16 05:26:14.4] INFO: Beginning the boostrap process for
>   DCC708A8-E3FF-4F7E-8D3E-30D5041F5AF2 (iPad mini 4, iOS SDK 13.3 at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot)
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:14.4] PERF:      - Waited 1ms to clean up
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:14.4] PERF:      - Waited 2ms for device to finish
>   creating
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:16.3] PERF:      - Booting time: 1907ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:16.4] WARN: Framebuffer unavailable; Xcode 10+
>   requires Library.Disposition.Local
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:16.4] PERF:      - Registering services: 11ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:29.2] ERROR: Could not find SimulatorBridge after
>   spawning it... bailing out.
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:29.3] ERROR: Service port lookup had failed with:
>   Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to
>   lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.2348: 0x3"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service
>   com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.2348: 0x3,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff884722c50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "No such process"}}
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:29.3] INFO: An unexpected error happened trying to
>   start the designer. Attempting to erase our device.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Simulator services were not
>   available after booting the simulator. Perhaps it has crashed.   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.LookupServices () [0x0009b] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.Start () [0x00312] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c7] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:289
>   [2019-12-16 05:26:29.3] ERROR: An exception occurred while launching,
>   forcibly restarting the session. [2019-12-16 05:26:30.9] PERF: Total
>   time for shutting down: 1571ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:33.2] INFO: Successfully killed the entire session
>   [2019-12-16 05:26:33.2] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 2):
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more
>   errors occurred. (Exception of type
>   'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.))
>   (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException'
>   was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException:
>   Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException'
>   was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase
>   contents and settings in current state: Booted"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings
>   in current state: Booted}   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x0001d] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:298
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:323
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse]
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession ()
>   [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.b__28_0
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type
>   'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. --->
>   Foundation.NSErrorException: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase
>   contents and settings in current state: Booted"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings
>   in current state: Booted}   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x0001d] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:298
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:323
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse]
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession ()
>   [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
>   <---
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:33.2] INFO: Invalidating all connections [2019-12-16
>   05:26:33.2] INFO: Beginning the boostrap process for
>   DCC708A8-E3FF-4F7E-8D3E-30D5041F5AF2 (iPad mini 4, iOS SDK 13.3 at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot)
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:33.2] PERF:      - Waited 1ms to clean up
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:33.2] PERF:      - Waited 3ms for device to finish
>   creating
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:34.9] PERF:      - Booting time: 1694ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:35.1] WARN: Framebuffer unavailable; Xcode 10+
>   requires Library.Disposition.Local
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:35.1] PERF:      - Registering services: 11ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:46.5] ERROR: Could not find SimulatorBridge after
>   spawning it... bailing out.
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:46.6] ERROR: Service port lookup had failed with:
>   Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to
>   lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.2348: 0x3"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service
>   com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.2348: 0x3,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff8868146e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "No such process"}}
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:46.6] INFO: An unexpected error happened trying to
>   start the designer. Attempting to erase our device.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Simulator services were not
>   available after booting the simulator. Perhaps it has crashed.   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.LookupServices () [0x0009b] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.Start () [0x00312] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c7] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:289
>   [2019-12-16 05:26:46.6] ERROR: An exception occurred while launching,
>   forcibly restarting the session. [2019-12-16 05:26:48.4] PERF: Total
>   time for shutting down: 1812ms
>
> [2019-12-16 05:26:50.7] INFO: Successfully killed the entire session
>   [2019-12-16 05:26:50.7] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 3):
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more
>   errors occurred. (Exception of type
>   'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.))
>   (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException'
>   was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException:
>   Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException'
>   was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase
>   contents and settings in current state: Booted"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings
>   in current state: Booted}   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x0001d] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:298
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:323
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse]
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession ()
>   [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.b__28_0
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type
>   'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. --->
>   Foundation.NSErrorException: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase
>   contents and settings in current state: Booted"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings
>   in current state: Booted}   at
>   MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x0001d] in
>   <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0    at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:298
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning
>   (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:323
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse]
>   (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean
>   throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession ()
>   [0x00001] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
>   <---

I have tried downgrading to 11.2, 11.21, Mac version 8.3.10 to no avail. No issues opening up a swift storyboard.

Comment: Does Xcode load the Storyboard?

Comment: Xcode loads the storyboard no issue. Using inbuilt designer for Xamarin(windows & mac) still has problems

Comment: @slushpuppy Have you checked with new Xamarin.iOS project , whether it work with storyboard.

Comment: Same issue for new storyboard. I am checking the coresimulator logs and I was getting notification hook error with teamviewer. Disabling teamviewer notification produces a new error <Error>: Bundle com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRenderingServices rejected boot with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={connectionUUID=A8F9E440-C57B-490B-88B4-93D987FDED11, message=Invalid connectionUUID specified.}

Comment: The teamviewer is probably a placebo, this error keeps appears in coresimulator logs Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.647: 0x3" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.647: 0x3, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000a952f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"}}

Comment: @slushpuppy Okey , you mean when creaing a new Xamarin.iOS project , the storyboard works . Issue just occurs  when adding new storyboard , the stroryboard can not load view .  Right ?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks for replying. Unfortunately no. The storyboard view doesn't work even if I add a new storyboard or create a new project. The only way I can view storyboard is by opening it up in xcode designer

Comment: @slushpuppy Okey , if also can not solve it , you can submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) in Github . After that , you can share the link here , we can follow it up .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks once again. Just to confirm- my project is Xamarin.IOS, do I still post the issue under xamarin.forms even for storyboard problem?

Comment: @SushiHangover No , that's a Froms Repo , I have updated with the Xamarin.iOS Repo . Thanks for reminding !

Comment: @slushpuppy Sorry , if not a Forms project .Here is the iOS Repo link [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues) :)

Answer (score 0):

See **Update** below for details.

I was able to fix this problem with the following command in mac os Terminal:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all
```

Then I tried opening storyboard and it successfully loaded.

**Update:** after two days of successful work I received the same message. I did command above, after that added `xcrun simctl erase all`, rebooted. Issue was still there. Finally I got how to fix it. **SOLUTION**: You should open xib, it will start spinning and during that open terminal and run `xcrun simctl shutdown all`. After that the issue will be resolved.